# kdd cup 1999 dataset, how to use it in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ip, data-mining, packet, intrusion-detection

I downloaded KDD99 dataset here: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/kddcup99-mld/kddcup99.html

After unzipping I tried to open it using datagrid in VS 2010 but it didn't work, I tried different softwares but none seems to work.

I am new and I need to use that dataset in my research project, but don't how to, I tried Google but found none.

The file is in unknown format, can any one tell me how to open it in visual studio or any other software?

If you don't know, please refer me to some site where I can find the answer.

Also if you know any website that is remotely related to kddcup99, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use this data set. It's flawed. http://www.kdnuggets.com/news/2007/n18/4i.html

> As a result, we strongly recommend that
>
> (1) all researchers stop using the KDD Cup '99 dataset,
>
> (2) The KDD Cup and UCI websites include a warning on the KDD Cup '99
>   dataset webpage informing researchers that there are known problems
>   with the dataset, and
>
> (3) peer reviewers for conferences and journals
>   ding papers (or even outright reject them, as is common in the network
>   security community) with results drawn solely from the KDD Cup '99
>   dataset.

Let me repeat **this data set must not be used for network-intrusion detection**. It does not reflect *reality*, it's simulated and old data. It looks ***nowhere* like any current attack pattern** anyway.

Other than that, the files should be ASCII text files. With good tools you don't need to extract it, because they can be decompressed on the fly (in fact, your webbrowser might be using this compression on the fly with some webservers)

For anything other than runtime benchmarking, don't use it.